# python debugger breakpoint to specific frame

Tags: python, debugging

I have a recursive function (example linked list traversal).

I have N nodes and I am decending in the linked list recursively.

I want attach debugger break point in N-1 th (penultimate frame), how do I do that ?

Comment: Add the breakpoint to the base case conditional suite?

Answer (score 1):

You can record how many times the function were called in the first run, and in the second run stop when the count reaches `n - 1` where `n` is the count you got in the first run.

You can use a **conditional breakpoint** to implement this, for example:

```
def count(f):
    n_called = 0
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal n_called
        n_called += 1  // Add a conditional breakpoint here
        print(f"{f} called {n_called} times")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@count
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)

print(factorial(5))
```

In the first run we got 5 times, and in the then we can set a `conditional breakpoint` on the line

```
        n_called += 1
```

In Pycharm or VSCode you can just right click the breakpoint and write a boolean expression, or use `condition bpnumber [condition]` if you are using a bare pdb.